# Installing IIS 7.5 through pkgmgr script on Windows 2008 R2

Tags: windows, iis, windows-server-2008-r2, dism

When trying to install IIS on Windows Server 2008 R2 Using the following script as described in [this technet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771209.aspx) I get errors about `"encountered unknown option "featurename" with the value .... "` for all of the features.

Script:

```
CMD /C START /w PKGMGR.EXE /l:log.etw /iu:IIS-WebServerRole;IIS-WebServer;IIS-CommonHttpFeatures;IIS-StaticContent;IIS-DefaultDocument;IIS-DirectoryBrowsing;IIS-HttpErrors;IIS-HttpRedirect;IIS-ApplicationDevelopment;IIS-ASP;IIS-CGI;IIS-ISAPIExtensions;IIS-ISAPIFilter;IIS-ServerSideIncludes;IIS-HealthAndDiagnostics;IIS-HttpLogging;IIS-LoggingLibraries;IIS-RequestMonitor;IIS-HttpTracing;IIS-CustomLogging;IIS-ODBCLogging;IIS-Security;IIS-BasicAuthentication;IIS-WindowsAuthentication;IIS-DigestAuthentication;IIS-ClientCertificateMappingAuthentication;IIS-IISCertificateMappingAuthentication;IIS-URLAuthorization;IIS-RequestFiltering;IIS-IPSecurity;IIS-Performance;IIS-HttpCompressionStatic;IIS-HttpCompressionDynamic;IIS-WebServerManagementTools;IIS-ManagementScriptingTools;IIS-IIS6ManagementCompatibility;IIS-Metabase;IIS-WMICompatibility;IIS-LegacyScripts;WAS-WindowsActivationService;WAS-ProcessModel;IIS-FTPServer;IIS-FTPSvc;IIS-FTPExtensibility;IIS-WebDAV;IIS-ASPNET;IIS-NetFxExtensibility;WAS-NetFxEnvironment;WAS-ConfigurationAPI;IIS-ManagementService;MicrosoftWindowsPowerShell
```

Log:

```
2010-09-07 14:20:04, Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: Host machine information: OS Version=6.1.7600, Running architecture=amd64, Number of processors=8
2010-09-07 14:20:04, Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: Executing command line: "C:\Windows\system32\dism.exe" /online /norestart /logpath:"C:\Users\administrator\Desktop\log.etw.txt" /enable-feature /ignorecheck /featurename:"IIS-WebServerRole" /featurename:"IIS-WebServer" /featurename:"IIS-CommonHttpFeatures" /featurename:"IIS-StaticContent" /featurename:"IIS-DefaultDocument" /featurename:"IIS-DirectoryBrowsing" /featurename:"IIS-HttpErrors" /featurename:"IIS-HttpRedirect" /featurename:"IIS-ApplicationDevelopment" /featurename:"IIS-ASP" /featurename:"IIS-CGI" /featurename:"IIS-ISAPIExtensions" /featurename:"IIS-ISAPIFilter" /featurename:"IIS-ServerSideIncludes" /featurename:"IIS-HealthAndDiagnostics" /featurename:"IIS-HttpLogging" /featurename:"IIS-LoggingLibraries" /featurename:"IIS-RequestMonitor" /featurename:"IIS-HttpTracing" /featurename:"IIS-CustomLogging" /featurename:"IIS-ODBCLogging" /featurename:"IIS-Security" /featurename:"IIS-BasicAuthentication" /featurename:"IIS-WindowsAuthentication" /featurename:"IIS-DigestAuthentication" /featurename:"IIS-ClientCertificateMappingAuthentication" /featurename:"IIS-IISCertificateMappingAuthentication" /featurename:"IIS-URLAuthorization" /featurename:"IIS-RequestFiltering" /featurename:"IIS-IPSecurity" /featurename:"IIS-Performance" /featurename:"IIS-HttpCompressionStatic" /featurename:"IIS-HttpCompressionDynamic" /featurename:"IIS-WebServerManagementTools" /featurename:"IIS-ManagementScriptingTools" /featurename:"IIS-IIS6ManagementCompatibility" /featurename:"IIS-Metabase" /featurename:"IIS-WMICompatibility" /featurename:"IIS-LegacyScripts" /featurename:"WAS-WindowsActivationService" /featurename:"WAS-ProcessModel" /featurename:"IIS-FTPServer" /featurename:"IIS-FTPSvc" /featurename:"IIS-FTPExtensibility" /featurename:"IIS-WebDAV" /featurename:"IIS-ASPNET" /featurename:"IIS-NetFxExtensibility" /featurename:"WAS-NetFxEnvironment" /featurename:"WAS-ConfigurationAPI" /featurename:"IIS-ManagementService" /featurename:"MicrosoftWindowsPowerShell"
......
2010-09-07 14:20:05, Info                  DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=1576 Encountered the option "featurename" with value "IIS-WebServerRole" - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::Private_GetPackagesFromCommandLine
```

Anyone know what might be happening here?

Comment: Update: If I use `CMD /C START /w PKGMGR.EXE /l:log.etw /iu:IIS-WebServerRole` only it installs.  So I am thinking maybe one or a few items in there is a culprit?

Comment: Which edition of Windows 2008 R2 are you running it on?

Comment: @squillman: Got it working, but using Standard.

Comment: If it makes you feel better, I'm getting the same thing when running on R2 Std :)  I'll see if I can get it to go as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following seems to have worked:

> CMD /C START /w PKGMGR.EXE /l:log.etw
>   /iu:IIS-WebServerRole;IIS-WebServer;IIS-CommonHttpFeatures;IIS-StaticContent;IIS-DefaultDocument;IIS-DirectoryBrowsing;IIS-HttpErrors;IIS-HttpRedirect;IIS-ApplicationDevelopment;IIS-ASP;IIS-CGI;IIS-ISAPIExtensions;IIS-ISAPIFilter;IIS-ServerSideIncludes;IIS-HealthAndDiagnostics;IIS-HttpLogging;IIS-LoggingLibraries;IIS-RequestMonitor;IIS-HttpTracing;IIS-CustomLogging;IIS-ODBCLogging;IIS-Security;IIS-BasicAuthentication;IIS-WindowsAuthentication;IIS-DigestAuthentication;IIS-ClientCertificateMappingAuthentication;IIS-IISCertificateMappingAuthentication;IIS-URLAuthorization;IIS-RequestFiltering;IIS-IPSecurity;IIS-Performance;IIS-HttpCompressionStatic;IIS-HttpCompressionDynamic;IIS-WebServerManagementTools;IIS-ManagementScriptingTools;WAS-WindowsActivationService;WAS-ProcessModel;IIS-WebDAV;IIS-ASPNET;IIS-NetFxExtensibility;WAS-NetFxEnvironment;WAS-ConfigurationAPI;IIS-ManagementService;NetFx3

Same But in in code tags:

```
CMD /C START /w PKGMGR.EXE /l:log.etw /iu:IIS-WebServerRole;IIS-WebServer;IIS-CommonHttpFeatures;IIS-StaticContent;IIS-DefaultDocument;IIS-DirectoryBrowsing;IIS-HttpErrors;IIS-HttpRedirect;IIS-ApplicationDevelopment;IIS-ASP;IIS-CGI;IIS-ISAPIExtensions;IIS-ISAPIFilter;IIS-ServerSideIncludes;IIS-HealthAndDiagnostics;IIS-HttpLogging;IIS-LoggingLibraries;IIS-RequestMonitor;IIS-HttpTracing;IIS-CustomLogging;IIS-ODBCLogging;IIS-Security;IIS-BasicAuthentication;IIS-WindowsAuthentication;IIS-DigestAuthentication;IIS-ClientCertificateMappingAuthentication;IIS-IISCertificateMappingAuthentication;IIS-URLAuthorization;IIS-RequestFiltering;IIS-IPSecurity;IIS-Performance;IIS-HttpCompressionStatic;IIS-HttpCompressionDynamic;IIS-WebServerManagementTools;IIS-ManagementScriptingTools;WAS-WindowsActivationService;WAS-ProcessModel;IIS-WebDAV;IIS-ASPNET;IIS-NetFxExtensibility;WAS-NetFxEnvironment;WAS-ConfigurationAPI;IIS-ManagementService;NetFx3
```

The above also seems to work fine as a startup script through group policy.

Comment: Good deal.  This worked on mine as well.  Will have to make a note to come back and research why removing the roles made it work.  Just to document, these are the roles not present in this command which were in the original post: IIS-FTPExtensibility, IIS-FTPServer, IIS-FTPSvc, IIS-IIS6ManagementCompatibility, IIS-LegacyScripts, IIS-Metabase, IIS-WMICompatibility, MicrosoftWindowsPowerShell.  And then NetFX3 was here but not in the first.

Comment: Thanks for posting the question and "solution" (quoted because in my case I was trying to enable IIS-Metabase feature using pkgmgr and it simly does not work - despite what MS posted in that technet article).  Perversely, using DSIM directly (as described here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/habibh/archive/2009/08/14/how-to-install-iis-7-5-on-windows-7-using-the-command-line.aspx) works fine.  The name of the feature is the same in DISM and pkgmgr.